# Usage of `Object#send` method as a best practice

Tags: ruby, ruby-style-guide

It is hard to identify the usages of code like below:

```
[:create, :update, :pause].each { |action| send("to_#{action}") }
```

Are there any other reasons that this is an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's reasons to use this, and there's reasons to avoid it. This trivial example is a case of an anti-pattern because it's a fixed array and it would be more concise to write:

```
create
update
pause
```

Where you have a case for using it is when the array isn't necessarily static, where there might be modifications, *especially* when used in the context of a DSL.

Rails employs this for the `before_validation` handler chain, for example, where it has a list of Symbol references or Proc functions to call:

```
before_validation :check_sanity
before_validation lambda { do_something(1) }
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not an anti-pattern. It's a part of the language. You should avoid it for the reasons mentioned but sometimes it's the only option. I don't think there are any significant drawbacks performance wise. As for keeping things OOP you should suggest switching to `public_send` - it's the recommended way.

Comment: I think the OP's point is that this pattern tends to be used where it is not necessary, and that inappropriate use is an antipattern.  I agree with him.